# 1990s fantasy novel series - Inexperienced water wizard fights fire mage

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am having a very hard time tracking down a book series.

1. It's about a young man who finds out he's a wizard and slowly gets trained up as one.
2. I think he specialised in water magic
3. In either the first or second book he has to defeat a fire Mage who is causing a great drought
4. There at least two books in the series and in the second one he meets a female Mage with similar powers to his own.
5. I have a very vague recollection that some of the household objects in his house could talk - could be wrong about that.
6. The first book was published around early 90s at least that's when I borrowed it.
7. The book was probably aimed at young adults
8. Definitely not a high fantasy novel, magic system was quite basic and a lot of it had to do with weather related stuff, i.e. floods and droughts.
9. I think in that world mages were very uncommon so his appearance was unexpected.

It's entirely possible that one or more of my memories are conflated with other series!

Comment: Do you remember *anything* else?

Comment: definitely not a high fantasy novel, magic system was quite basic and a lot of it had to do with weather related stuff I.e floods and droughts. I think in that world mages were very uncommon so his appearance was unexpected.

Comment: Uhhh... brain appears to think it knows this but is just tossing up wacky theories... I've got Kelvin of Rud series and The Innocent Mage, even though I know it's not the latter and can't actually remember the former.

Comment: I remember Kelvin... *Dragon's Gold*, *Chimaera's Copper*, whatever third book was...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I started looking it up just to clear my head and *Copper* is actually book 3 out of 5.  It does have some evil magic emperor cliché but otherwise didn't seem to match.  Talking housewares just makes me think Piers, I guess.

Comment: Could this br Janny Wurts' _Cycle of Fire_ series (_Stormwarden_, _Keeper of the Keys_, _Shadowfane_)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janny_Wurts

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might be considering the [Mancer](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/593955.Pyromancer) series by Don Callander. It starts with *Pyromancer* with a sequel of *Aquamancer*.

[image: Cover for Aquamancer]

Comment: Dmoonfire, thank you as well! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

This is the Mancer Series by Don Callander. The 1st book, Pyromancer, was published in 1992.  The main character is a young man named Douglas Brightblade, who becomes apprenticed to a Master Pyromancer. The home they live in has pieces of have furniture/kitchen tools/utensils that are semi-animate. Much like Beauty and the Beast. The main Antagonist is actually an Aeromancer, who is slowly freezing the world.

The 2nd book, Aquamancer, is where he meets a young lady who becomes apprenticed to a Master Aquamancer.

The spark of magic in this world was rare and a dying art, the young man and woman were the first apprentices their Masters had in a long time.

The series was aimed at Young Adults. Read these when I was in high school.

Comment: Can you possibly add some excerpts from the books? To make it easier for the OP to identify this as the correct answer. What you have is pretty good though.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the series well done and thank you. I've been looking for years and you solved it on such scant information in less than a day. Thanks so very much. Sorry for the late reply too, I had a few personal matters which kept me offline.

Comment: No, problem! Thanks for the question. Your question is the first one I could answer with at least 90% certainty that I was correct. =)